# findInterval not working with R data.frame and a lookup table

Tags: r

I am trying to use findInterval to find which quartile a list of numbers belongs to (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th).

I have a lookup matrix:

```
> lookup
               0%      25%      50%      75%     100%
apple    3.846154 13.88889 18.11594 22.96296 47.22222
banana   5.882353 16.03694 20.53429 25.58937 47.82609
cucumber 6.060606 15.38462 18.75000 23.06815 39.47368
doritos  4.347826 14.43110 17.67830 22.81101 38.70968
elephant 7.582938 16.01732 18.71921 23.23232 36.28692
frog     2.439024 14.55696 18.70504 22.52252 36.14458
gorilla  3.448276 15.49895 19.59184 23.21852 34.78261
hangover 3.750000 10.71378 15.09434 18.09857 34.61538
```

and a data.frame

> DF
>   Source: local data table [1,426 x 2]

```
        cat      rate
     (fctr)     (dbl)
1   doritos  9.803922
2  hangover 22.968198
3    banana 12.658228
4  cucumber 12.643678
5  elephant 11.299435
6   gorilla 15.481172
7     apple 23.163842
8      frog 38.461538
9   doritos 14.563107
10 hangover 14.634146
..      ...       ...
```

but when I run:
`DF$level = findInterval(DF$rate, lookup[as.character(DF$cat), ], rightmost.closed = TRUE)`

I get this error: `Error in findInterval(DF$rate, lookup[as.character(DF$cat), ], rightmost.closed = TRUE) : 
  'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs`

Despite the matrix being sorted. I can add sort() like so: `DF$level = findInterval(DF$rate, sort(lookup[as.character(DF$cat), ]), rightmost.closed = TRUE)`

But then I get strange numbers:

```
> DF
Source: local data table [1,426 x 3]

        cat      rate level
     (fctr)     (dbl) (int)
1   doritos  9.803922  1426
2  hangover 22.968198  4992
3    banana 12.658228  1605
4  cucumber 12.643678  1605
5  elephant 11.299435  1605
6   gorilla 15.481172  2497
7     apple 23.163842  5170
8      frog 38.461538  6417
9   doritos 14.563107  2140
10 hangover 14.634146  2140
```

If I run the command on a single row of the data.frame, it seems to work with or without the sort:

```
> findInterval(DF$rate[1], sort(lookup[as.character(DF$cat[1]), ]), rightmost.closed = TRUE)
[1] 1
> findInterval(DF$rate[2], lookup[as.character(DF$cat[2], ]), rightmost.closed = TRUE)
[1] 4
```

I've managed a workaround by using `percent_rank` and then categorizing each row based on the level, but still would like to know why this isn't working. I imagine I am missing something about vectorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The category and rate must be placed into the function one at a time. `findInterval` will not vectorize through `DF$rate` as is. The function `mapply` allows us to do this:

```
DF$level <- mapply(function(x,y) {
  findInterval(x, lookup[as.character(y), ], rightmost.closed = TRUE)},
  DF$rate, DF$cat
)
DF
#         cat      rate level
# 1   doritos  9.803922     1
# 2  hangover 22.968198     4
# 3    banana 12.658228     1
# 4  cucumber 12.643678     1
# 5  elephant 11.299435     1
# 6   gorilla 15.481172     1
# 7     apple 23.163842     4
# 8      frog 38.461538     5
# 9   doritos 14.563107     2
# 10 hangover 14.634146     2
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
DF %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(level=findInterval(rate, lookup[as.character(cat),],
                                 rightmost.closed=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Could this translate into something usable with dplyr's mutate? I get a Don't know how to handle type pairlist when I try the same method with mutate(DF, ...)
edit: looks I can use rowwise(DF) %>% mutate(level=findInterval(...)) and avoid mapply all together.